# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer Delay when switching from Video & taking capturing image in still image mode

Tags: ios, swift

I Am using a library for creating custom camera on my swift app using the camera and video https://github.com/yonat/CameraBackground

But I am getting a delay & the camera will take an image using the flash when the flash setting is off
when switching my camera mode from video to still image and I'm trying to take an image after changing the outputs

unfortunately, if I don't set a delay it will return a dark image.

The code:

```
@IBAction func startCapture(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.background(delay: 0.1, background: {
        // do something in background
        let currentSession =  self.previewLiveCamera.cameraLayer?.session
        currentSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        currentSession!.addOutput(AVCaptureStillImageOutput())


    }, completion: {
        // when background job finishes, wait 3 seconds and do something in main thread

        self.previewLiveCamera.takeCameraSnapshot( {
            // animate snapshot capture
            print("Starting...")
        },
          completion: { (capturedImage, error) -> () in
            if capturedImage != nil {
                print("compleated with image")
                RZTransitionsManager.shared().defaultPresentDismissAnimationController = RZZoomAlphaAnimationController()
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "post") as! PostViewController
                nextViewController.image = capturedImage
                nextViewController.transitioningDelegate = RZTransitionsManager.shared()
                self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.previewLiveCamera.removeCameraBackground()
                    self.addvideoCamBackground()
                    self.hideCaptureBtns()
                    self.progressView.popIn()
                    self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
                })

            }

        })
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage from CameraBackground Readme:

```
view.addCameraBackground()
// ...
view.takeCameraSnapshot( {
    // animate snapshot capture
    self.view.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { self.view.alpha = 1 }
}, completion: { (capturedImage, error) -> () in
    self.view.freeCameraSnapshot() // unfreeze image
    // ... handle capturedImage and error
})
// ...
view.removeCameraBackground()
```

you can see, in usage is used this interval to set visibilty, so if you delete delay from your code, alpha stays 0. So use it how is described in GitHub with your code:

```
view.addCameraBackground()

view.takeCameraSnapshot( {
    print("Starting...")
    self.view.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { self.view.alpha = 1 }
}, completion: { (capturedImage, error) -> () in
    self.view.freeCameraSnapshot()
    if capturedImage != nil {
        print("compleated with image")
        RZTransitionsManager.shared().defaultPresentDismissAnimationController = RZZoomAlphaAnimationController()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "post") as! PostViewController
        nextViewController.image = capturedImage
        nextViewController.transitioningDelegate = RZTransitionsManager.shared()
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.previewLiveCamera.removeCameraBackground()
            self.addvideoCamBackground()
            self.hideCaptureBtns()
            self.progressView.popIn()
            self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
        })

    }
})

view.removeCameraBackground()
```